# What is the correct URI to send to handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap?

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I have the common problem of display a picture in the correct rotation. My images are stored on a server. I call an image and display it in my app. Each image is rotated. So I found a correction with handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap.

```
public static Bitmap handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(Context context, Uri selectedImage)
        throws IOException {
    int MAX_HEIGHT = 1024;
    int MAX_WIDTH = 1024;

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    InputStream imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
    imageStream.close();

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);

    img = rotateImageIfRequired(img, selectedImage);
    return img;
}
```

But it's impossible for me to send the correct Uri selectedImage.

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon = null;
            final String myUrlStr = urldisplay;
            URL url;


            try {
                url = new URL(myUrlStr);
                uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(urldisplay));
                uri2 = Uri.parse((urldisplay).toString());

                mIcon = handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(getContext(),uri2);
               } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I have the error

```
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = new URL(DataConstantes.lien_URLEtb + "Aucune_photo_etablissement.png").openStream();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                flagError = true;
            }
            mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            flagError=true;
        }
```

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /http:/$$$$$$$$$$/appli/android_connect/Etablissement/abordage.jpg (No
>   such file or directory)

Do you know how I can send the correct URI ?

Thanks

Comment: If you had a correct url you would send it correct. But the url is a http url which cannot be handled by bitmap factory and such. Download the file first yourself.

Comment: @blackapps thanks... I don't understand your answer. Before trying to rotate, I have used InputStream in = new URL(urldisplay).openStream(); mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in) so the url can be handled by bitmap factory. In this case, the problem is to convert urldisplay in Uri to enter in handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap

Comment: You dont have to explain your code. It's completely wrong. You have a file not found exception because you use a file input stream upon a http url. Google how to download a file.